# Touch event does not dismiss keyboard in Sencha?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, keyboard, sencha-touch

I have an issue in my Sencha app where a touch action somewhere on the screen does not dismiss the keyboard; in fact I have this issue for all my Sencha apps. Is this a general issue? And is there a solution? I don't want to have to hit the dismiss button, or call call blur() every time I want to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I posted a work-around over in the Sencha Touch forums - basically disabling fields will force the keyboard to close](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141560-Sencha-Touch-Android-show-and-hide-keyboard-with-code&p=726323&viewfull=1#post726323)

Answer (score 0):

whatever textfield is first responders should be resigned being the first responder. Tapping somewhere on the screen wont help as the view you are most likely tapping does not ask for being the first resonder.

```
[youTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I'm developing in Javascript, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

After further research in the Sencha forums I have discovered that this is a bug in Sencha 1.0. Hopefully Sencha 2.0 will have fixed this issue. :P